# UINavigationController for table inside of UITabController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

my app is built with a UITabController and works as imagined. However, for one of the views within my UITabBar, I would like to add a table that when something is pressed will take me somewhere. And I would like to do this just within this one view.

I know how to build a table and populate and get it to go somewhere but my issue is I can't seem to get my app to run with the table. I feel like my connections are off and specifically with appDelegates. I already had two appDelegate files (.h & .m) before adding the UINavigationController so from here I really don't know what to do. I took apple's simpleTableView tutorial files and copied them over to mine. It still crashes. I even copied there appDelegate files (so now I have 4) but the same deal. This is the error I am getting but in general I just feel lost with the delegates and connections.

2011-12-12 12:08:50.302 TabbedCalculation[68713:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key delegate.'
*** Call stack at first throw:

If anyone can offer any help, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S. I have changed within the mainWindow.xib of the UITabController to point one of the tabs to the appropriate class and xib file so that is not the issue but I have noticed that many tutorials want within the app delegate this line to the navController: 
                   [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

but I have already set it to the tabBarController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app can only use one set of app delegate files. So copying over a the example's app delegate files does not mean they are being utilized. You need a navigation controller inside the specific tab you want to contain the tableview. Here is an example of a navigation controller inside a tab bar controller, by modifying `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    AllTaskViewController *view1 = [[AllTaskViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AllTaskView" bundle:nil];
    view1.title = @"All Tasks";

    TodayTaskViewController *view2 = [[TodayTaskViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TodayTaskView" bundle:nil];
    view2.title = @"Today's Tasks";

    HistoryViewController *view3 = [[HistoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HistoryView" bundle:nil];
    view3.title = @"History";

    SettingsTableViewController *view4 = [[SettingsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsTableView" bundle:nil];
    view4.title = @"Settings";

    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view1];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view2];
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view3];
    UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view4];

    [view1 release];
    [view2 release];
    [view3 release];
    [view4 release];

    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1, nav2, nav3, nav4, nil];

    [nav1 release];
    [nav2 release];
    [nav3 release];
    [nav4 release];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    

    return YES;
}
```

Note: All 4 view controllers have an individual navigation controller, and each one is a custom view controller. I used nibs here, but you don't necessarily have to. And the app itself has no main window, you would need to modify this slightly if you are using a main window for the app.

Comment: Thank you very much! When you say main window, what are you referring too? my app loads to the first tab as soon as the splashscreen disappears

Comment: On older versions of XCode, created projects were run through a MainWindow.xib file. But now, when you create a tab bar controller project in iOS 5.0, everything is created programmatically. If you don't notice a MainWindow.xib in your project bundle, then don't worry about it. And please accept my answer if it works for you. Good luck.

Comment: I happened to had started my project iOS 4:S. So yes I have the MainWindow.xib file... it gives me just a blank white screen when I run things but no crashes. I will accept your answer but can you explain a little bit more what needs to be done with the MainWindow.xib file? It would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, if you would like to implement my code directly, then click on the big label with the name of your project at the top of XCode's file browser to get your app's main info (where you edit app icons). Then move down to the section titled "iPhone/iPod Deployment Info" and make sure "Main Interface" is blank (it should say MainWindow.xib). If you would like to use MainWindow.xib, then you'll have to put use Interface Builder to put a tab bar controller in your Main Window view and link it to your code.

Comment: wow this is kind of embarrassing but I can't find it... I went all the way to the top of the file browser list and selected the one with the blue xcode icon aka the name of my project. From here I see projects and targets, each section seems to have build settings. Is it within this?

Comment: No, the first one. Things have changed slightly since [this image](http://www.techotopia.com/images/2/2b/Ipad_ios4_xcode_main_window.jpg) was captured, but it should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, you have truly been a great help and I really appreciate it. If you don't mind (I know I have a thousand questions, this is my last one I promise) telling what the property to manually setting the image for each tab and width is? I see what you did with setting the title for each view, is picture similar such as self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed: your image];?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5790/discussion-between-gurooj-and-teddy13)